# What is the difference between class componentName extends Component {} and export class componentName extends Component {}

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js, and I've been trying to figure out the real difference between code block A and code block B below. Why does code block B's class definition begin with the keyword 'export' but at the bottom still exporting default Products?

Code block A:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Products extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
          //bla, bla, bla
       )
    }
}

export default Products;
```

Code block B:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Products extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
          //bla, bla, bla
       )
    }
}

export default Products;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class Foo
export class Bar
```

let's you import individual objects like

```
import { Foo, Bar } from '../someFile.js'
```

whereas

```
export default Foo
```

lets you import it as a single component like

```
import Foo from '../someFile.js'
```

You can have both in the same file but you can only have 1 default export per file where as the other way you can export as many components as you like.

**EDIT:**

```
export class Products extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
          //bla, bla, bla
       )
    }
}

export class ProductCategories extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
          //bla, bla, bla
       )
    }
}

export default Products;
```

which can then be imported like

```
import Products, { ProductCategories } from './myFile.js'
```

OR

```
import { Products, ProductCategories } from './myFile.js'
```

Comment: can you please provide code examples for the scenarios of "you can have both in the same file and you can export as many components as you like."? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're doing it in code block B! A default and non-default export. Edit the answer anyway.

Comment: Is it true that my original question's code block A and code black B work exactly the same even though the class definition of block A does NOT have the keyword 'export'???

Comment: Creating and exporting a module are 2 different things. This is es6 101. I suggest you read the official docs to get a better understanding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export